# Why pointers are faster and more efficient

Tags: c++, c, performance, pointers

I read this in a [C book](http://www.amazon.in/Understanding-Using-Pointers-Richard-Reese/dp/1449344186) :

> Pointers have several uses, including: • Creating fast and efficient
>   code • Providing a convenient means for addressing many types of
>   problems • Supporting dynamic memory allocation • Making expressions
>   compact and succinct • Providing the ability to pass data structures
>   by pointer without incurring a large overhead • Protecting data passed
>   as a parameter to a function. **Faster and more efficient code can be
>   written because pointers are closer to the hardware. That is, the
>   compiler can more easily translate the operation into machine code.**
>   There is not as much overhead associated with pointers as might be
>   present with other operators.

Q. How is 'compiler translating operations into machine code easily' related to faster working of code ? It could be easier for the compiler to convert, but how does it affect the speed of created executable ?

Q. Since, everything gets converted into the machine instructions at the end, how is using pointers gonna give some special speedup if I rather pass say normal variables ?

Could someone give some insight on how using pointers could make program faster ?

**P.S.** I understand that instead of passing a massive 'object', passing a pointer would be better in terms of resources being copied, is there anything more to it because of which pointers are preferred ?

Comment: If using pointers is "faster" or not depends on *how* the pointers are used.

Comment: throw the book.

Comment: Maybe it is trying to say that it is easier to translate code using pointers and would therefore result in less instructions to do the same thing?

Comment: @bolov: It's C, not C++. Maybe longjump the book?

Comment: Is there a first part to that comparison?

Comment: What's the context? What is the book talking about there? Without knowing that it's hard to know if the claim has any merit, or to explain it further.

Comment: return the book, then!

Comment: @Deduplicator I have added some more context.

Comment: @sth  I have added some more context.

Comment: Somebody is writing such a thing like that in an O'Relly book from last year? I hope that you misread this somehow, because stated like this it seems completely wrong to me. Modern architectures all have relative addressing that can do array offsets without any additional cost.

Comment: @AmitTomar you've answered your own question already.  Forgive my over-analysis.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Do not agree with "Modern architectures all have relative addressing".  IN 2014, simple embedded processors are not well known to have a 0 cost relative addressing.

Comment: @chux, there may be some processors (or toolchains) that aren't able to optimize. But writing a general statement like that, without mentioning just that it is much, much platform dependent would be negligence.

Comment: The book isn't only C. The summary you linked to gives a summary that implies the audience is both C and C++ programmers: _"This comprehensive book has the information you need, whether you're a beginner or an experienced C or C++ programmer or developer."_. As such you should tag this question C and C++.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That quote claims that code using pointers is faster, but it doesn't say faster *than what*.

The most common claim is that code using pointers is faster than equivalent code using array indices. For example:

```
char s[] = "hello, world";
char *p = s;
while (*p != '\0') {
    /* do something with *p */
    p ++;
}
```

vs.

```
char s[] = "hello, world";
int i = 0;
while (s[i] != '\0') {
    /* do something with s[i] */
    i ++;
}
```

Very old c compilers might have generated significantly faster code for the first version than for the second. For modern optimizing compilers, it's unlikely to make any difference. A good compiler might even generate exactly the same machine code for both (I haven't tested this).

It's more important to write *clear* C code and let the compiler generate the best machine code to implement it.

Comment: I disagree somewhat. When a `char[]` is used this way, it decays to a `char*` anyways. But you're off in the right direction – The first thing that came to mind for me was the difference between indexing though a `char*` versus a C++ `std::vector<char>`. The former is often a single instruction that the compiler groks perfectly and can vectorize, the latter is usually a function call. Code that uses this sort of access in a `vector` is almost never vectorized, unless you've got a compiler which has special knowledge of `vector`.

Comment: The question is tagged C, so `std::vector` is irrelevant.

Comment: Your first statement applies here: _faster than what_? C arrays decay to pointers in this context (in most contexts), and there isn't any other tool that C provides that achieves the same thing as pointers. Moreover the summary of the book that OP linked to ends with "_This comprehensive book has the information you need, whether you’re a beginner or an experienced C or C++ programmer or developer._". Knowing that the book's audience includes C++ programmers can shed light on why that statement was made.

Comment: They don't generate the same machine code.  The first snip increments the memory location itself, so there would be a cmp [location], value instruction.  The second snip increments the memory offset, so there would be at least two instructions -- one to add the base location of the array and the offset being incremented and another to compare the value stored in the memory location to the null value given.

Comment: @JustKevin, not the same assembler, probably true, but most likely not more statements. Modern architectures happily to relative addressing.

Comment: And if they don't generate the same op codes, snip 1 consumes at least as many cycles as snip 2.  The burden would then be on you to show they consume the same number of cycles.

Comment: @JustKevin Both are liable to generate exactly the same compiled code. I'm sure most compiler developers (especially the big teams) would treat sub-optimal code for #1 as a severe problem needing a timely fix.

Comment: @JustKevin: Whether they generate the same machine code depends on the compiler. They certainly *can* result in exactly the same machine code because they have the same visible behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson more obvious speedup is passing struct and pointer to struct as function operands then indexing an array ... (which significantly impact heap trashing and memory size needed to transfer). also function pointers are nice to avoid if's or switch statements

Answer (score 1):

That is absolutely true -- pointers and references are closer to the machine language.  The point that your text is making is more about copying data in a "deep" copy vs. assigning a memory location in a "shallow" copy.  I know full well that this is absolutely true.  As an example, Visual Basic can be somewhat ambiguous in comparison to C++ in this regard (perhaps off topic, but still relevant) and I was able to make a multiplication routine run on the order of a hundred times faster with larger memory spaces owed to the fact that I was able to avoid most of the allocations and data juggling that was going in VB, by implementing the algorithm with pointers and references in C++.

*If you have an array and a routine that needs to read from the array, it's much much faster to copy only the memory location of the data structure rather than the entire contents of the target data structure and that goes for any programming language.  The only rule you need to follow is that if you write to the memory passed by reference or pointer it will alter the original data structure.*

Comment: "absolutely true" ? No, not really. Modern architectures happily do relative addressing with a base register and an offset. No need for pointers at all to be efficient.

Comment: How does the compiler know where the variables are? If you have an 'int Value;'  the compiler sees it as a memory location.  If you have a 'void *Pointer;' the compiler sees it as a memory location as well, but a memory location holding a memory location.  When you use large data structures it is an absolute that you do not want to be juggling your data around on the stack and doing all kinds of deep copy routines, so I stick by both my statement and my comment above.

Comment: Anyway, never forget the "as-if-rule", and what startling optimizations modern compilers can perform.

Comment: Best practice is not to assume specific optimizations will occur.

Comment: Do you have concrete evidence that pointers are faster (*than what*) **in C**? Note that the question isn't about C++ or Visual Basic.

Comment: Faster than copying the entire dataset into a function that only needs to read the dataset, for one.  'struct' was, in fact, originally part of the C language.

Comment: Certainly there are cases where code using pointers is faster than code not using pointers. The claim is that pointers are *generally* faster (than what??), and you seem to be saying that this is always the case.  It isn't.  See my answer.

Comment: I provided a counter example.  I challenge you to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Only the code using pointers is faster than equivalent code using array.but the pointer is never stored in a register it lives in main memory.

But variable does not have to live in main memory. Depending on the circumstances, the compiler can store it in a register for all or part of its life, and accessing a register is much faster than accessing RAM.

Accessing via "pointer" (rather than directly) DOES involve (a bit) of extra work and (slightly) longer time.

Exactly the same thing occurs whether or not it's a pointer variable (C or C++) or a reference variable (C++ only).

But the difference is enormously small.